# How can I combine test filters in the unit testing framework Google Test?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have several unit test cases, which I have written with the Google Test framework:

1. Test class:

   ```
   class Test: public testing::Test
   {
   public:
     virtual void SetUp() {}
     virtual void TearDown() {}
   };
   ```
2. Actual tests:

   ```
   TEST_F(Test, SubTest1)
   {
     // execute Test logic
   }

   TEST_F(Test, SubTest2)
   {
     // execute Test logic
   }

   TEST_F(Test, SubTest3)
   {
     // execute Test logic
   }
   ```

> Assumed that I want to display only `SubTest1` and `SubTest3`, what do I have to do? Important is, that I want to see at a central place (main method), which tests are actually executed.

I thought, that I can "stack" filters as in the following example, but this approach did not work:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);

  ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "Test.SubTest1";
  ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "Test.SubTest3";
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

→ The second filter removed the first one and only `SubTest3` is executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to find some official `googletest` reference, but I only found [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taxiahou/2013/07/30/the-usage-of-running-a-subset-of-tests-in-google-test-framework-gtest_filter/) explaining the syntax of googletest filters. If you want to run testcases matching one of 2 different patterns, your filter should look like:

```
"FIRST_PATTERN:SECOND_PATTERN"
```

So, in your case:

```
  ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "Test.SubTest1:Test.SubTest3";
```

You can also use wilcards `?` and `*` and you can add exclusion patterns after `-` sign.

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Also nice, that you mentioned the usage of wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable tests you don't want to run with `DISABLED_` prefix ([see documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#temporarily-disabling-tests)):

```
TEST_F(Test, DISABLED_SubTest2)
{
  // execute Test logic
}
```

The test will still be compiled, but GoogleTest will not run it.

GoogleTest provides a nice information after tests finish, how many of them were disabled.

You can also temporarily enable them with `--gtest_also_run_disabled_tests` flag.

Comment: But I dont have a list with executed tests in the main method. I didn't write this, but I want to see at a central place (main method), which tests are actually executed.

Comment: This smells of a bad design and violates DRY principle. Why do you need a list of executed tests? Will you update the list with each new test? What if you forget to add test to the list? What if you want to change fixture name?

Comment: To some extent you might be right, however I want a simple overview of my actually executed tests, where I might "parse" different test suites. Unit tests don't need a perfect design in my use case and don't underlay any guide lines or something like this.